# Using AsyncTask to implement API and updating result to UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using AsyncTask in an API to carry out the network operations. At UI part there is a button, clicking on which triggers API to execute request/async task. API is implementing the callback which is updated from onPostExecute() method. API gets the right data populated once onPostExecute() passes data over to callback. This all works good. But I'm getting some conceptual problem while updating to UI. This is what I want to achieve:
1- Click "Button" on UI
2- I want to update API's response string to UI. This response string I get after executing AsyncTask.

The problem is that API always return null as response in the current thread of execution. Once UI thread is done, I see the API/AsyncTask data coming in. I know I'm missing something very trivial, but important. Do you know whats the right way to update API response on UI?

**[Update]**

Here is my UI code which includes clicking button triggering async task via API (just another class which implements callbacks for getting server response)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                            API api = new API();
            Request request = new Request();
                    request.setUrl("http://www.example.com/");
                    api.fetch(request);

            try {
//It doesn't matter how much you wait here to return the response. 
//Response from task doesn't return in this thread. 
//If I click another button say "refresh" to refresh the data, then api.getResponseString() shows the response from server.
                Thread.sleep(2000);
//api.getResponseString() returns null. I expect it to return data just retrieved from server
                String text = api.getResponseString();
                System.out.println("Text: " + text);
                textView.setText(text);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**API Code**

```
public class Api implements ResponseCallbacks {

String responseString = null;

public void fetch(Request request) {
    makeRequest(request, this);
}

public void makeRequest(Request request,
        final ResponseCallbacks responseCallbacks) {
    MyTask asyncTask = new MyTask();
    asyncTask.setResponseCallbacks(responseCallbacks);
    asyncTask.execute(request);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(Response response) throws IOException {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        responseString = "Success";
    } else {
        responseString = "Failed";
    }
}

public String getResponseString() {
    return responseString;
}
}
```

**AsyncTask Code**

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask {
private ResponseCallbacks responseCallbacks;

public MyTask() {}

public void setResponseCallbacks(ResponseCallbacks callbacks) {
    this.responseCallbacks = callbacks;
}

@Override
protected Response doInBackground(Request... params) {
    Request request = params[0];
    Response Response = null;

    try {
        //Make Http call and gets response from remote server here...
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return response;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        try {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                callbacks.onSuccess(response);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            callbacks.onFailure(response);
        }
    }
}


}
```

What I want is to update the text returned from server in textView after I click button.

***[Update 2]***
Apparently, I found out that if I define one more callback say UICallback and have my activity register with it, solves the problem.

**UICallback:**

```
public interface UICallback {
public void onFailure(String response);
void onSuccess(String response) throws IOException;
}
```

Have Activity implement it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements UICallback {
    .......
    api = new NetApi();
api.setUICallbacks(this);
    .......

    @Override
public void onSuccess(String response) throws IOException {
    String text = api.getResponseString();
//works !
    textView.setText(text);

}
}
```

Does anyone have better solution than this ? I really don't like the idea of Activity implementing an extra callback. It would have been awesome, if my api itself could deliver the server response once done fetching data, just by api.getResponseString().

Comment: Can you please post some code. It will give us better understanding of what you are trying to achieve. We would be able to help you in better way.

Comment: as per Shobhit said, need code snippet to understand you better.

Comment: Post your code in asynctask & button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, what you're looking for is actually [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

If you use this in `onPostExecute`, you can refresh your UI data without registering callbacks and whatnot. Like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {
  if (response.isSuccess()) {
    try {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(text);

                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        callbacks.onFailure(response);
    }
  }
}
```

A synchronous alternative would be using the Runnable in the main thread. You'd have to redefine MyTask to implement `Runnable` and `join` immediately after. Like this

```
Thread asyncTask = new Thread(MyTask());
asyncTask.start();
asyncTask.join();//gets called as soon as the task ends
```

MyTask would be

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable{

     public void run(){
         //do whatever you need to do
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep UI code separated and want to access server response via API. Code above needs UI component to be accessed from Asynctask code and that exactly, I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Look at my amended answer. It uses java Threads instead of the AsyncTask you were using. The main difference is, of course, that this method isn't necessarily asynchronous. Careful, though: it might get your app into a state where it's waiting for a response and is classified as non-responsive.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think callback method seems more appropriate so far in my case. Thanks for taking time in discussion.

Comment: you're welcome! And for the record, I agree: launching, and waiting, for a Thread to join would in this case probably just make your App unresponsive.